# NinePatchDrawable -> Bitmap -> NinePatchDrawable

Tags: android, nine-patch

I have a nine patch drawable in my resources. I have to change some of its colors at runtime by saving NinePatchDrawable as Bitmap and changing pixels and then saving this Bitmap as NinePatchDrawable again.

My code:

```
Bitmap src = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, resId);
Bitmap bitmap = src.copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888, true);
//... pixels operation

byte[] chunk = bitmap.getNinePatchChunk();
return new NinePatchDrawable(res, bitmap, chunk, new Rect(), null);
```

The app crashes on 'new NinePatchDrawable' with following:

```
"Signal Catcher" daemon prio=5 tid=4 RUNNABLE
   | group="system" sCount=0 dsCount=0 obj=0x40517900 self=0xe89f0
   | sysTid=21817 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=[no-cpu-subsys] handle=473072
   | schedstat=( 1007082 4364014 23 )
   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)
 [<c0294308>] save_stack_trace_tsk+0x0/0x90
 [<c03b5568>] proc_pid_stack+0xf8/0x144
 [<c03b68cc>] proc_single_show+0x48/0x84
 [<c038aef8>] seq_read+0x26c/0x4e4
 [<c0371ab8>] vfs_read+0xa8/0x150
 [<c0371c0c>] sys_read+0x3c/0x68
 [<c0290740>] ret_fast_syscall+0x0/0x30
    [<ffffffff>] 0xffffffff
    ------------------------------
"main" prio=5 tid=1 RUNNABLE
   | group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x400281f8     self=0xd190
   | sysTid=21814 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=[no-cpu-subsys]     handle=-1345002240
   | schedstat=( 1833007809 896209717 2404 )
   at     android.graphics.NinePatch.validateNinePatchChunk(Native Method)
   at android.graphics.NinePatch.<init>(NinePatch.java:50)
   at android.graphics.drawable.NinePatchDrawable.<init>(NinePatchDrawable.java:73)
```

What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

When I used nine patch chunk from source bitmap instead of new bitmap it worked:

So instead of:

```
byte[] chunk = bitmap.getNinePatchChunk();
```

should be:

```
byte[] chunk = src.getNinePatchChunk();
```